# O parâmetro "javax.faces.source" não aparece quando uso a tag update="#{principalControle.updateAlterarCadastroGenerico}" em um p:commandButton

Tags: jsf-2.2

Estou utilizando `PhaseListener` para validar permissão de usuário. E quando utilizo a tag Update com biding não consigo visualizar o parâmetro `javax.faces.source` na requisição.

**HTML que funciona:**

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="# cadastroGenericoControle.alterarCadastroGenerico}" >
</p:commandButton>
```

**HTML que não funciona:**

```
p:commandButton  update="#{principalControle.updateAlterarCadastroGenerico}"
    actionListener="#{cadastroGenericoControle.alterarCadastroGenerico}" >
</p:commandButton>
```

**Codigo java**

```
public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {

    Map<String, String> params =event.getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    boolean achouParametro = params.containsKey("javax.faces.source");

    ***quando não utilizo `update="# principalControle.updateAlterarCadastroGenerico}"` no botão, a variável `achouParametro` está `true`, e quando utilizo está `false`.*** 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro era causado porque estava utilizando "@(:" para atualizar o componente.

**Codigo que provocava o erro**

```
public String getUpdateAlterarCadastroGenerico(){
        return "@(:panelPesquisar),@(:panelAlterar)";
}
```

**Codigo que corrigiu o erro**

```
public String getUpdateAlterarCadastroGenerico(){
        return "panelPesquisar,panelAlterar";
}
```